# jQuery sortable IE issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Running into an issue with a simple implementation of jQuery's sortable in IE9 only.
I have an ordered list with jQuery's sortable on it. When I drag and drop one of the items into a new position all the numbers change to that number.

Has anyone run into this issue before? I can't seem to track down any leads.

Using jQuery 1.7.1 & jQuery UI 1.8.13

My markup looks like:

```
<div id="movieList">
     <div class="col">
          <ol>
              <li id="" class="add" style="">
                   <span>Select Movie</span>
              </li>
              <li id="" class="add" style="">
                   <span>Select Movie</span>
              </li>
              <li id="" class="add" style="">
                   <span>Select Movie</span>
              </li>
              <li id="" class="add" style="">
                   <span>Select Movie</span>
              </li>
              <li id="" class="add" style="">
                   <span>Select Movie</span>
              </li>
          </ol>
     </div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript I have implemented is:

```
$('#movieList .col ol').sortable();
$('#movieList .col ol').disableSelection();
```

I uploaded a couple images of the results here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv3Hy.jpg

Thanks in advanced,
Smccullough

Comment: this may have to do with you not specifying IDs on the list items.

Comment: do you mean jQuery version 1.7.1 instead of 1.7.7?

Comment: Ooops, I did mean 1.7.1. My seven key got too excited.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code running on jsbin.com. I tested in IE 9 and it works fine. http://jsbin.com/elegig/4.

Comment: Thanks for setting up that test Bodonix. The example works well in my IE9 as well. There has to be a simple reason for the result I'm getting with the setup I have.